# ¿Pasar de Milisegundos a Horas Java Server Faces?

Tags: java, mysql

Buen dia para la siguiente consulta, tengo una variable Long a la cual le asigno la resta de dos Datetime, La variable diferencia me almacena el resultado en Milisegundos pero yo los necesito en horas para guardarlos en mi columna de tipo Float y no me guarde esto -8.5322904E7 como modificar este metodo de antemano agradecido.

```
 public void botonTerminarTiempo() {

    tiempos.setFechaHoraFinal(fechaActual);
    tiemposFacade.edit(tiempos);        
    Long diferencia = (tiempos.getFechaHoraInicio().getTime() - tiempos.getFechaHoraFinal().getTime());        
    tiempos.setTotalHoraHombre(diferencia.floatValue());
    tiemposFacade.edit(tiempos);
    fechaActual = new Date();
    laborSeleccionada = new Labor();
    lineaSeleccionada = new Linea();
    operarioSeleccionado = new Operarios();
    ordentrabajo = new Ordentrabajo();
    tiempos = new Tiempos();
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuántos minutos tiene una hora? ¿Cuántos segundos un minuto?...

Comment: Recuerda votar por la respuesta que mas te ayudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la clase [TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) así:

```
long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliseconds);
```